Sending private transactions on the BSC chain
I know that on the ethereum chain there exists flashbots to avoid sending your transaction directly to the mempool. How can I do the same thing on the Bsc Chain? I want to send my transaction directly to validators without the need to send it publicly and then to have to wait for it to be picked up by some miner. Is there to do it?
